# How to extend a Python scipy.stats class?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, scipy

I am trying to add a method to an existing Python scipy.stats class but it is generating a `_construct_docstrings` error.

```
import scipy.stats as stats

class myPoisson(stats.poisson) :
  def myMethod(var, **kwargs) :
    return var
```

I have tried adding an `__init__` method with a call to `super().__init__(self)` but this has not changed the error.

What am I missing for extending existing Python classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scipy.stats distributions are *instances*, not classes (for historic reasons). Thus, you need to inherit from e.g. `poisson_gen`, not `poisson`. Better still, inherit from `rv_continuous` or `rv_discrete` directly. See the docstring of rv_continuous for some info on subclassing distributions

Answer (score 1):

hopefully the following example helps you out.

```
def myMethod(var, **kwargs):
    return var

stats.poisson.myMethod = myMethod

stats.poisson.myMethod(2)
```

Refer to [Adding a Method to an Existing Object Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance][1]) for further details on the topic.